# Convert a column with nested XML into tabular format in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

DDL and sample data:

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (OwnerID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, House XML);

INSERT @tbl (House) 
VALUES (N'<House>
              <Room id="111111" type="b" name="Master Bedroom" formatstring="">
                  <Closest>3</Closest>
                  <Windows>4</Windows>
              </Room>
              <Room id="222222" type="a" name="Guest Bedroom" formatstring="">
                  <Closest>1</Closest>
                  <Windows>2</Windows>
              </Room>
              <Room id="333333" type="a" name="Bathroom" formatstring="">
                  <Closest>0</Closest>
                  <Windows>2</Windows>
              </Room>
              <Room id="444414" type="b" name="Kitchen" formatstring="">
                  <Closest>1</Closest>
                  <Windows>0</Windows>
              </Room>
         </House>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end
```

Here is my attempt to shred the `House` column into individual columns via T-SQL:

```
...
```

Desired output:

| OwnerID | id | type | name | formatstring | Closest | Windows |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111111 | b | Master Bedroom |  | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 222222 | a | Guest Bedroom |  | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 333333 | a | Bathroom |  | 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 444414 | b | Kitchen |  | 1 | 0 |

SQL Server version: `SELECT @@VERSION;` emits the following:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM-CU5) (KB5026806) - 16.0.4045.3 (X64)   
May 26 2023 12:52:08   
Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation  
Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 19045: )
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Also, the provided XML is not **well-formed**.

Comment: Please advise what you have attempted and where you got stuck.

Comment: What is a "Closest"? https://duckduckgo.com/?q=define%3AClosest&ia=definition Should it be closet?

Comment: What does the final output look like? Please provide the "expected result" e.g. does it include a "closest" column or columns? and windows column or columns? How many room types are there? e.g. could these be used? Parlor, Salon, Music Room, Hamman, En Suite, Guest Suite 6, Second Master Bedroom, Nursery, Limonia etc etc etc

Comment: I edited your question, and converted it into a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You just need to provide #2 now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT
    OwnerID,
    RoomId = xc.value('@id', 'int'),
    RoomType = xc.value('@type', 'varchar(50)'),
    RoomName = xc.value('@name', 'varchar(50)'),
    FormatString = xc.value('@formatstring', 'varchar(50)'),
    Closets = xc.value('(Closest/text())[1]', 'int'),
    Windows = xc.value('(Windows/text())[1]', 'int')
FROM
    @tbl
CROSS APPLY
    House.nodes('/House/Room') AS XT(XC)
```

That should return the desired data for you.

You're basically "shredding" the XML into a list of XML fragments for each `<Room>` element under the `<House>` root node, and then accessing that `<Room>` elements and picking out the various **attribute** values (`id`, `type` etc.), as well as accessing some of the subelements and getting their values

**Update**

If you want to support multiple `<Closet>` as well as `<Windows>` subelements - try something like this:

```
SELECT
    OwnerID,
    RoomId = xc.value('@id', 'int'),
    RoomType = xc.value('@type', 'varchar(50)'),
    RoomName = xc.value('@name', 'varchar(50)'),
    FormatString = xc.value('@formatstring', 'varchar(50)'),
    Closets = xc2.value('(./text())[1]', 'int'),
    Windows = xc3.value('(./text())[1]', 'int')
FROM
    @tbl
CROSS APPLY
    House.nodes('/House/Room') AS XT(XC)
CROSS APPLY
    XC.nodes('Closet') AS XT2(XC2)
CROSS APPLY
    XC.nodes('Windows') AS XT3(XC3)
```

Comment: I’m encountering another issue where it’s possible to have multiple similar XML elements. 
Ie: 2 or more <closet> within the same <Room>. However, the current code does not account for that. 
Can you advise?

Comment: @Xoom: well, that's a whole new question, really - but basically, you'll need a second level of `CROSS APPLY` to handle multiple subelements in a `<Room>` XML element ....

Comment: This works gloriously when I added 1  additional CROSS APPLY for “closest” only. However, this progress is lost when I try to apply a second CROSS APPLY for “windows” for a total of 3 in my query. Using the same logic, I get an error.  Can you advise how 3 cross apply can successfully be implemented?

Comment: @Xoom: updated my response showing how to handle two sets of multiple subelements under `<Room>`

Comment: Thank you, sir. 
As a new user, they won’t let me upvote your post until I get 15 credit scores. I was able to replicate this using “outer apply” to get all the null values. Thank you!